# elisp - How to copy lines from a buffer effectively

Tags: elisp

I want to use elisp to copy lines from a buffer. for example: copy line 100 to 200 text to another buffer.

Should I select the region (goto-line) then copy it? just like what we do with keyboard? Some post say do not use goto-line in elisp code. I don't know what's effective way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function `copy-lines-from-buffer` that's similar to [`copy-to-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/copy_002dto_002dbuffer.html) except that it works with line numbers instead of points, and unlike `copy-to-buffer` it does not erase the current contents of the target buffer:

```
(defun copy-lines-from-buffer (buffer start-line end-line)
  "Copy the text from START-LINE to END-LINE from BUFFER.
Insert it into the current buffer."
  (interactive "*bSource buffer: \nnStart line: \nnEnd line: ")
  (let ((f #'(lambda (n) (goto-char (point-min))
               (forward-line n)
               (point))))
    (apply 'insert-buffer-substring buffer
           (with-current-buffer buffer
             (list (funcall f start-line) (funcall f end-line))))))
```

The `copy-lines-from-buffer` function takes either a buffer or buffer name as its first argument, the start line number as its second argument, and the end line number as its third. It creates a local helper function `f` that returns point at the beginning of line `n` of the current buffer, and it calls `f` twice with the current buffer set to `buffer` to create a list consisting of the starting point and ending point of the desired buffer contents. It then uses `apply` to invoke `insert-buffer-substring` with `buffer` and the buffer contents start and end points as arguments.

Call `copy-lines-from-buffer` from the point in your buffer where you want the contents to be inserted. The contents of the start line are included in the copied content, but the contents of the end line are not included.

Comment: Great, it's exactly what I want!